# HP laptop can't turn on WiFi

Tags: windows-10, connection, wireless-adapter, broadcom

I've a HP G42 laptop. Normally I use Internet using WiFi. It has a Broadcom 802.11n network adapter.

Today I was browsing and suddenly my PC restarted, after that I tried to turn on WiFi but it won't turn on.

The wireless switch key(F12) works well (turns orange when wireless is off and white when it's on). But within Windows 10, it's always off.

I've tried switching it from Win10 settings app, but the WiFi switch **elastically** falls back to off state every time I click it.

I've tried updating my Broadcom driver which I downloaded in my phone (yes, Wifi works on other devices) but no change.

Diagnosing & troubleshooting says that to turn on WiFi but how can I start a thing which is broken itself? Tried dual-booting Win7 from another drive but the case is exactly same.

Maybe it's a hardware issue, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you have the same issue on Windows 7 as on Windows 10, then it is very likely that the wifi hardware is broken. See if you have warrantee

Comment: I once fought a similar problem.It turned out the machine also had a hardware switch for the wireless.

Comment: @Lenne the hardware switch is the key F12. OP mentions it has tried that already.

Comment: F12 is a software-switch. There _could_ be a hardware switch too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check that there is no hardware WiFi switch (like a sliding button on the edge of the laptop, or a press button) that you would have touched accidentally.
2. Try accessing your BIOS when starting the computer, and check in it that the WLAN (WiFi) is turned on.
3. In Windows 7: Start > Computer (right click) > Manage > Device Manager > Network cards. If the driver is installed, your wireless card should be listed here. (The procedure should not be much different in Windows 10.)

Comment: True. It could have a hardware switch that is a point to look into

Comment: There's no H/W or physical switch.

Answer (score 1):

In control panel go to device manager . Uninstall the wireless device DO NOT click "delete driver software for this device".
[image: Device manager wifi adapter]
 Restart the PC then go back to device manager in click file then click scan for hardware changes this should resolve your issue
[image: Scan for hardware changes]

Comment: I have used it on many machines to reset the wifi unless it is a hardware issue this solves it each time . Had a similar issue a while back. But alas it looses all your wifi passwords but at least it works.  I think it an internal misconfiguration that affects wifi nic cards

Answer (score 0):

I hear ! you’ve been having difficulty with your [Hp Laptop Won’t Connect to internet](https://keepsdisconnecting.com/hp-laptop-wont-connect-wifi/)   There’s a couple different options to resolve this issue and I’ll be happy to point you in the right direction!

To get started, let’s change your security type.  Changing to WEP may remedy the issue.  The way this is completed may vary depending on your router, but the general way to do this will start by going to [http://192.168.1.254](https://#) on a computer connected directly to your U-verse router.  From here, you’ll go to your wireless settings and change it to WEP-Open.  You may also need to change your wireless password to work with WEP.  After doing this, save your changes.

If this doesn’t do the trick, I recommend updating the driver of your Wi-Fi adapter on your HP Laptop.  You can do this in the Device Manager of your laptop.  To do this, search for Device Manager in the Windows search bar.  Open the Device Manager and expand the component you want to update.  From here, right click and select Update Driver Software > Search automatically for updated driver software.  Follow the on-screen instructions and restart your computer to complete the installation of the updates.

Please let me know how this works for you!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Answer (score -1):

this one is an old post but may be useful my answer for another one...if you have some hardware knowledge find the WiFi card and remove it and start your machine.shutdown again and refit the card. start the machine and check the result...

Comment: Why would this (possibly) help?